# Ios safari black highlight focus on element

Tags: ios, css, html, safari, focus

In safari when we tap and hold element, for example input textfield, element highlithing with black translucent color on whole element. I need remove it, I tried `-webkit-appereance:none` but it doesn't help me. can you help me with this, how i can remove black highlight on focus event?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change

```
#container {
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
}
```